# Join one to many distinct

Tags: sql-server

I have two tables which I want to join, each table has a unique id. the first table has one record per unique id, the second table has many records per unique id. In the joins result set I want one record from the table with many records per unique id. It doesnt matter what record.

one record/unique value

```
-----------------------
id|other values
1 | blah
2 |blah
3 |blah
```

mutliple records/unique value

```
-----------------------------
id|code
1 | bv11
1 | bv11
1 | bv11
```

desired result

```
--------------
id|code
1 | bv11
2 |bv12
```

Comment: Where does bv12 come from ?

Answer (score 2):

Here is a way to do it where you can get however many fields you want from each tabl:

```
select u.*, m.code
from Unique u left outer join
     (select m.*, row_number() over (partition by id order by (select NULL)) as seqnum
      from Multiple m
     ) m
     on u.id = m.id and
        m.seqnum = 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way I can think of off the top of my head would be to join table 1 to a grouping of table 2 where you group by id and take, e.g., min of every other column you need.

Something like

```
select a.id, bx.code from a, (select id, min(code) from b group by id) bx
where a.id = bx.id
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 SELECT TM.id,
        TM.code

 FROM   TABLE_UNIQUE TU



        INNER JOIN TABLE_MULTIPLE TM ON

        TU.id = TM.id


GROUP BY TM.id, TM.code
```